# MLE of $\mu$ when $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d $N(\mu,\mu^2)$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

**The Question:**

Given independent random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n \sim N(\mu,\mu^2)$ where $\mu>0$ is unknown, find the MLE $\hat \mu$ of $\mu$.

---

**My Attempt:**

Yes, I know this is a really standard question, but I got a really strange answer so I am not sure. We go through the usual drill:

$$L(\mu)=(2\pi \mu^2)^{-n/2}\exp\Bigl(\frac{-1}{2\mu^2} \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2 \Bigr)$$

$$\ell (\mu)=-\frac n2 \ln(2\pi\mu^2)-\frac{1}{2\mu^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2 $$

\begin{align}
\ \frac{d\ell}{d\mu} & = \Bigl(-\frac n\mu\Bigl)+\Bigl(\frac{1}{\mu^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)\Bigl)+\Bigl(\frac{1}{\mu^3}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2\Bigl) \\
\ & = \Bigl(-\frac n\mu \Bigl) -\Bigl(\frac n\mu +\frac{1}{\mu^2}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i \Bigl)+ \Bigl(\frac{1}{\mu^3}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-\frac{2}{\mu^2}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+\frac n\mu \Bigl) \\
\ & = -\frac n\mu - \frac{1}{\mu^2}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+\frac{1}{\mu^3}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2
\end{align}

Thus

\begin{align}
\ & \frac{d\ell}{d\mu}=0 \\
\ \implies & n\mu^2+\mu \sum_{i=1}^nx_i-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2=0 \\
\ \implies & \mu = \frac{-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i + \sqrt{\bigl(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i \bigr)^2+4n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}}{2n}
\end{align}

... and I feel that I have done something wrong, since there is no way I can use this disgusting thing to do the next part of the question.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Interesting question. I feel what you have done here is all right. What is the next question, btw? 
As an alternate approach, you can try out $L(\mu, \sigma)=(2\pi \sigma^2)^{-n/2}\exp\Bigl( \frac{-1}{2\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2 \Bigr)$ for likelihood and use lagrange multipliers for the constraint that $\mu = \sigma$

Comment: The next part is to show that the asymptotic variance of $\hat \mu$ is $\mu^2/3n$

Comment: Never mind, I got it XD

Comment: So, is your approach correct? Request you to share how you proceeded with the asymptotic variance as well. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to view the PDF you have attached in the link. Would you care to explain how you get that expression?

Comment: Well, it was two years ago but Stubborn's answer about MLE is not correct in this case - the linked pdf assumes the distribution has an **equal** variance and mean. Here we have $\mu \neq \mu^2$ (most of the time).

Comment: @НикитаВасильев You are right. Just happened to come across this post again. The answer derived by OP is correct whenever $\sum X_i>0$. (this was also asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/369417/119261)).

Answer (score 3):

OK, so seems like there is nothing wrong with that disgusting expression for $\hat \mu$. The next part of the question is to show that the asymptotic variance is $\mu^2/3n$ which actually does not require the expression for $\hat \mu$:

\begin{align}
\ \frac{d^2 \ell}{d \ell ^2} & = \frac{d}{d \ell}\Bigl(-\frac n\mu-\frac{1}{\mu^2}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+\frac{1}{\mu^3}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\Bigl) \\
\ & = \frac{n}{\mu^2}+\frac{2}{\mu^3}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-\frac{3}{\mu^4}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 \\
\end{align}

Hence, the asymptotic variance is the reciprocal of the Fisher Information, which is:

\begin{align}
\ I(\mu)^{-1} & =\biggl(\Bbb E\Bigl[-\frac{d^2 \ell}{d \ell ^2}\Bigr]\biggr)^{-1} \\
\ & =\biggl(-\frac{n}{\mu^2}-\frac{2}{\mu^3}\sum_{i=1}^n\Bbb E(x_i)+\frac{3}{\mu^4}\sum_{i=1}^n\Bbb E(x_i^2) \biggr)^{-1} \\
\ & = \biggl(-\frac{n}{\mu^2}-\frac{2}{\mu^2}(n\mu)+\frac{3}{\mu^4}(2\mu^2)\biggr)^{-1} \\
\ & = \frac{\mu^2}{3n}
\end{align}

noting that $\Bbb E(x_i^2)=Var(x_i)+[\Bbb E(x_i)]^2=\mu^2+\mu^2=2\mu^2$